Azure Synapse Analytics - output not displayed
Following Scala code in Azure Synapse should print: Hello, World!. But instead, it prints: defined object Geeks.
Question: What could be the issue and how can we fix it?
object Geeks { 

// Main method 
def main(args: Array[String]) 
{   
    // prints Hello, Geeks! 
    println("Hello, World!") 
} 
}

UPDATE:
I encounter the exact same issue when I run the above notebook in Databricks Community edition from Databricks company.

Can you clarify how you run this code in Azure Synapse? A notebook?

@GaëlJ, That's correct. A notebook. After reading your comment, I have also just added an UPDATE section - just in case.

When you define an object with a  main  method in a notebook, the object is compiled and loaded into memory, but the  main  method is not automatically executed. To execute the  main  method, you need to call it explicitly outside of the object definition. Below is the way to call the main function inside the object,
Geeks.main(Array())

Here, I gave an empty array value as it doesnot have any impact for this code. You can pass the required arguments while calling different objects.


Nicely explained. It worked - thank you.

@NaveenSharma Oops!!. I forgot to accept his solution - although I had given him +1. Thank you for reminding me - it indeed helps the SO community, and we should all do it when it resolves the issue described in the post.
